# Is it possible to enable Axis logging in a QSYS2.HTTP_GET_VERBOSE request?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a service that I am consuming and I would like to be able to add a trace if there's a problem. I've previously added trace to Axis implementations when using the C-APIs on IBMi, but I am switching to the SQL implementation because it's easier to use. The documentation for the HTTP_* functions (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=programming-http-functions-overview) provides relevant links and points me to (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/enabling-client-trace-web-services-client), which I hope will allow me to add the trace using the new functions.

I tried adding a `"ClientLogPath" : "/var/tmp/axis/testLog.log" , "LogFilter" : "transport;noEntryExit"` to the options parameter, but I received an "Invalid Property" error. Can I add trace to a QSYS2.HTTP_GET_VERBOSE() request? If so, how? Thanks.